# HP Omen 870-224 Motherboard upgrade

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade

Just purchased a Gigabyte B365 Ultra Durable Intel LGA 1151 mATX Motherboard for my HP Omen 870-224. I had no issues booting the PC without the CPU but once I installed the CPU and fan, it wouldn't boot, just power on for 1 second and turn off. Are the CPU from HP Omens "locked" with the manufacture Motherboard or did I snag a faulty board?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you do not have a compatible CPU for your Gigagbyte B365 motherboard. The CPU on the HP Omen is possibly a 7th Gen i5-7400, or any processor compatible with the H170 chipset. The Gigabyte motherboard is only compatible with Coffee Lake (8th and 9th Gen) CPU.

It is very important to understand that even though CPUs from 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th Gen use the same LGA1151 socket, they are not necessarily compatible with a motherboard or chipset! Be sure to check the compatibility between each other before buying a new part.

Here is a list of compatible CPU for your new board:
https://www.gigabyte.com/ca/Motherboard/B365-HD3-rev-10/support#support-cpu

There is no way to lock a CPU to a specific board or brand. HP Omen PCs are simply a custom built PC, which use parts built for speed, at a low cost.

Comment: Thank you! What motherboard would your recommend for that particular CPU? or would purchasing a new CPU be easier?

Comment: A new CPU would be easier, and more future proof. You simply need to leave your PC as is and pop in the new CPU when you receive it. A new motherboard might be cheaper though, since a CPU equivalent to yours is still over 200$.    If you can return your board, then get one of these: https://turbofuture.com/computers/best-z270-kaby-lake-motherboard-200 or https://graphicscardhub.com/best-motherboard-under-100-gaming/   Be sure to choose one that's for 6th or 7th Gen Intel!

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver!